# How to select from string array added in SQL column?

Tags: sql, arrays, select, where-clause, sql-like

Below is my table,

```
create table t(
   id int,
   colParam varchar(max))

insert into t values(1,'["param1", "param2"]')
insert into t values(2,'["param2"]')
insert into t values(3,'["param1"]')
insert into t values(4,'["param2", "param3"]')
insert into t values(5,'["param1", "param2"]')
```

**tried**

```
declare @str varchar(max) = 'param1'; Select * from t where colParam like '%'+ @str+'%'
```

**its not working for**

```
declare @str varchar(max) = 'param1,param2'; Select * from t where colParam like '%'+ @str+'%'
```

i want to select rows by passing `colPar as 'param1,param2'` so it will result me all the records containing param1 and param2 in colParam

Comment: So based on your sample data it should return only ID=1 and 5?

Comment: No, i should return all, because param1 and param2 exists in all records. When i say param3 it should return Id =4, on param1 it should return Id =1,3,5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quiet tricky.

```
create table #t(
    id int,
    colParam varchar(max)
)

insert into #t values(1,'["param1", "param2"]')
insert into #t values(2,'["param2"]')
insert into #t values(3,'["param1"]')
insert into #t values(4,'["param2", "param3"]')
insert into #t values(5,'["param1", "param2"]')

declare @str varchar(max) = 'param1,param2';
```

**to Return all matching values.**

```
select distinct id, t1.colParam  from #t t1
cross apply string_split(t1.colParam, ',') t2
cross apply string_split(@str, ',') t3
where t2.value like '%'+t3.value+'%'
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I tried with the cross apply before but used only once in query. Your efforts solved my query and time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 and above, then you can use `STRING_SPLIT`.

[As MSDN says:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> A table-valued function that splits a string into rows of substrings,
>   based on a specified separator character.

So your can look like this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    id int,
    colParam varchar(max)
)

insert into @t values(1,'["param1", "param2"]')
insert into @t values(2,'["param2"]')
insert into @t values(3,'["param1"]')
insert into @t values(4,'["param2", "param3"]')
insert into @t values(5,'["param1", "param2"]')

SELECT 
  t.id
, s.col
FROM @t AS t
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT 
    spl.value AS col
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(
        (SELECT _t.colParam FROM @t AS _t WHERE _t.id = t.id), ',') AS spl
 )s
```